# Calling a function in json from a jqgrid custom button

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with some data. When two of the rows are selected, I'd like to add a record in the database (in a different table than the one of the jqgrid). What I do is to create a new button in the navigation bar with the following code:

```
    jQuery("#tabla").navButtonAdd('#navegacion',
        {
            caption: "Crear tramo", buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink", cursor:"pointer", title: "Crear tramo",
            onClickButton: $(function() {   
                 var selectedrows = $("#tabla").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                 var er1=$("#tabla").jqGrid('getRowData',selectedrows[0]);
                 var er2=$("#tabla").jqGrid('getRowData',selectedrows[1]);

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',                                  
                    url: 'json/operaciones.jsp',                                                                    
                    postData: { oper:'add', id1:er1, id2:er2},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })                                
            })
    });
```

And what I have in the file operaciones.jsp is:

```
    <%

            String salida="";

            DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("my", "Connection", "Parameters");

            try {

                    System.out.println("Parámetros enviados:");
                    Enumeration e=request.getParameterNames();
                    while (e.hasMoreElements()){
                            String par=(String)e.nextElement();
                            System.out.println(par+":"+request.getParameter(par));
                    }



            String operacion=request.getParameter("oper");
            String id1=request.getParameter("id2");
            String id2=request.getParameter("id2");
            String comentarios="prueba";


            if (operacion.equals("add")) {

                    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(
                            "INSERT INTO TRAMOS "+
                            "(COMENTARIOS,ELEMENTOS_REGISTROCODIGO,ELEMENTOS_REGISTROCODIGO2, ENTIDADESCIF) "+
                            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                    stmt.setString(1,comentarios);
                    stmt.setString(2,id1);
                    stmt.setString(3,id2);
                    stmt.setString(4,"Q1818002F");

                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                    stmt.close();
                    salida="{\"correcto\":true,\"clave\":\""+id1+"|"+id2+"\",\"mensaje\":\"OK\"}";
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    String cadenaError=e.toString().substring(e.toString().indexOf(":")+2);
                    cadenaError=cadenaError.replace('\n',' ');
                    cadenaError=cadenaError.replace("\"","\\\"");
                    salida="{\"correcto\":false,\"clave\":\"\",\"mensaje\":\""+e.toString()+"\"}";
            }
            finally {
                    con.close();
            }
        System.out.println("salida:"+salida);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
    %>     
    <%=salida%>
```

But it's not working, what I get is "java.lang.NullPointerException". Where is the mistake? How can I send the data to the file operaciones.jsp?
Thanks in advanced, 
Natalia

Answer (score 1):

One clear error in the code which you use is the usage of `postData` instead of `data` and `mtype` instead of `type` as parameters of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

I recommend you additionally to write more safe code. For example you use `selectedrows[0]` and `selectedrows[1]` inside of the `onClickButton` before verifying that `selectedrows` is not `null` and that `selectedrows.length > 1`. If the user click for example on the button before at least two lines are selected one get exception in JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I did what you mention. What happens now is that operaciones.jsp gets the "oper" string correctly, but not id1 or id2. But it works fine if I write the id directly (i.e. id1:1254).

Comment: @NataliaGenaro: I don't guaranteed that my suggestion fixes all problems in the code which you posted. You don't posted the definition of the columns (`colModel`) from the grid which you use. So I don't know the values `er1` and `er2` which you post. Additionally I don't use Java myself so I can't help you in fixing of your Java code. The names `id1` and `id2` seems me strange. You post *objects* returned from `getRowData(selectedrows[i])` and not ids `selectedrows[i]`. Moreover you use `String id1=request.getParameter("id2");` (`"id2"` and not `"id1"`). You should *debug* your code.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid error... What finally worked:

```
       jQuery("#tabla").navButtonAdd('#navegacion',
                {
                    caption: "Crear tramo", buttonicon: "ui-icon-extlink", cursor:"pointer", title: "Crear tramo",
                    onClickButton: function() {                       
                        selectedrows = $("#tabla").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                    if(selectedrows.length==2){
                        er1=$("#tabla").jqGrid('getRowData',selectedrows[0]);
                        er2=$("#tabla").jqGrid('getRowData',selectedrows[1]);                       
                        $.ajax({
                            datatype:'json',
                            type:'GET',
                            url:'json/operacionesTramos.jsp',
                            data:{oper:'add',id1:er1.codigo,id2:er2.codigo},
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert("Tramo creado");
                            }
                        })  
                        }
                        else{
                        alert("Seleccione dos arquetas, por favor");                     
                        }                   


                    }
            });
```

Thanks Oleg!